# How to deploy a database file and connect to it with EF Core SQLite

Tags: uwp, entity-framework-core

For our UWP app we have a database file filled with some masterdata. We want to ship this database file with the application. Now, I can not figure out how to set the connection string in the Entity Framework DbContext. Normally, we use "Filename=Filename.db" as connection string. With this, you can create a database in the "LocalState" Folder. We deploy the database as 'Content' and 'copy if newer'. I can't connect to this database file, relative path is not working. Maybe there is a better setup for our scenario. Any recommendations?

Comment: Finally I solved the issue with a SQliteConnection which I inject into the options builder. It works fine with absolute path which I get with  <br /> `Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation`  <br />


 `protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)  <br />        {
            var connection = new SqliteConnection(_connectionString);
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(connection);
        }`

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test right now but have you tried with the "ms-appx:////dbFile.db" path ?
You will only get a read access to your application folder.

If you want to alter the file, you will have to copy it to your application cache folder.